# actualSize of groupColumnDef in aggrid is wrong

Tags: ag-grid

I need to autosize the columns width based on content. All columns resize just fine except for the groupColumnDef, for some reason the actualSize value is a lot smaller than what it should be.[image]

I did not set minWidth/width/maxWidth in the column def.
What could be the issue?

Answer (score 3):

```
// grid.component.html

<div style="text-align:center">
  ag-grid Example
</div>
<ag-grid-angular #agGrid style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" class="ag-theme-balham" [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
  (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
</ag-grid-angular>


// employee.ts

export interface Employee {
    name: string;
    age: number;
    country: string;
    year: number;
    date: number;
    month: string;
    ssn: number;
    address: string;
    zipCode: number;
    occupation: string;
    employer: string;
    employerAddress: string;
    mobNum: number;
}


// grid-component.ts

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { GridOptions } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { Employee } from './models/employee';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})

export class GridComponent implements OnInit {
  gridOptions: GridOptions;

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.setGridOptions();
  }

  setGridOptions() {
    this.gridOptions = {
      suppressColumnVirtualisation: true
    } as GridOptions;
  }

  onGridReady(params) {
    this.setData();
  }

  setData() {
    this.gridOptions.api.setColumnDefs(this.getColumnDefinitions());
    this.gridOptions.api.setRowData(this.getData());
    this.autoSizeAll();
    this.gridOptions.api.refreshCells();
  }

  getColumnDefinitions(): Array<any> {
    return [
      {
        field: 'name',
        headerName: 'Name'
      },
      {
        field: 'age',
        headerName: 'Age'
      },
      {
        field: 'country',
        headerName: 'Country'
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Birth Day',
        children: [
          {
            headerName: 'Year',
            field: 'year'
          },
          {
            headerName: 'Month',
            field: 'month'
          },
          {
            headerName: 'Date',
            field: 'date'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        field: 'ssn',
        headerName: 'Social Security Number'
      },
      {
        field: 'address',
        headerName: 'Address'
      },
      {
        field: 'zipCode',
        headerName: 'Zip Code'
      },
      {
        headerName: 'Occupation Details',
        children: [
          {
            field: 'occupation',
            headerName: 'Occupation'
          },
          {
            field: 'employer',
            headerName: 'Employer'
          },
          {
            field: 'employerAddress',
            headerName: 'Employer Address'
          },
        ]
      },
      {
        field: 'mobNum',
        headerName: 'Mobile Number'
      }
    ];
  }

  getData(): Employee[] {
    return [
      {
        name: 'Mary Smith',
        age: 25,
        country: 'Australia',
        year: 1990,
        date: 14,
        month: 'March',
        ssn: 1234542792102229,
        address: '31 Rainbow Rd, Towers Hill, QLD 4820 31 Rainbow Rd, Towers Hill, QLD 4820',
        zipCode: 11350,
        occupation: 'Engineer',
        employer: 'MicroSoft',
        employerAddress: '245 Rainbow Rd, Microsoft, Towers Hill, QLD 4820',
        mobNum: 7156662910
      },
      {
        name: 'Jeff Martin',
        age: 30,
        country: 'UK',
        year: 1987,
        date: 24,
        month: 'December',
        ssn: 1234542792102229,
        address: '31 Rainbow Rd, Towers Hill, QLD 4820',
        zipCode: 11350,
        occupation: 'UI/UX Designer',
        employer: 'Facebook India',
        employerAddress: '17 Rainbow Rd, Towers Hill, QLD 4820',
        mobNum: 7158462910
      }
    ];
  }

  autoSizeAll() {
    const allColumnIds = [];
    this.gridOptions.columnApi.getAllColumns().forEach((column: any) => {
      allColumnIds.push(column.colId);
    });

    this.gridOptions.columnApi.autoSizeColumns(allColumnIds);
  }

}
```

Here what I have done is

1. In html - Bind gridOptions and onGridReady event
2. In Component

   - Initialize the grid options and set suppressColumnVirtualisation = true.
   - When the grid is ready set data to the grid by setting the column definitions and then row data.
   - Get the column ids of all the columns in the grid and set them in grid api autoSizeColumns.

autoSizeColumns() looks only at the cells already rendered on the screen. Therefore the column width is set based on what it sees. This happens due to column virtualization. So the columns not visible on the screen will not auto size.

This behavior can be bypassed simply by setting **suppressColumnVirtualisation = true**

> Note that grid use this column virtualization to improve the
>   performance of the grid when there are large amount of columns to be
>   rendered.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately it doesn't work for me specifically for the group column. Maybe because I have a pretty complex cell renderer, not sure. It would be too complicated to add a snippet but I appreciate your try to help. As a semi-solution I added a reasonable minWidth.

Comment: Thats sad to hear. If you code base is available somewhere may be i can have a look